# String of n length in java

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int N=sc.nextInt();
    String s="";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
       s=sc.nextLine();
    }
```

Eg : N= 10
S = aabbbabbab

How do I take an input of String of n length ?
I am trying to take an input String which must be of length N.
I know the above logic is wrong, but still i am confused ?
PS: The first line of input contains a single integer N − the length of the string. 
The second line contains the initial string S itself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. Do you mean you do you guarantee that the string is get is length n?

Comment: Edited the question. Yes, the string which is to be input must be of n length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the input String is greater than the `maximumlength`.

```
if (s.length() > maximumLength) { // do something
```

And what you can do is to use a substring in order to trim the input.

```
fixedInput = s.substring(0, maximumLength - 1);
```

Okay, as you are reading the number first, you must initialize `maximumLength` with the first input.

As an alternative you can ask the user until the input fits the entered length:

```
do {
   s = sc.nextLine();
   if (s.length() != maximumLength)
      System.out.println("The input did not fit the size");
} while (s.length() != maximumLength);
```

Comment: I believe the first option is more efficient, but the second answer is good if the user needs to grab only the first n characters and then leave the input source alone after that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = sc.nextInt(); // N == 5 e.g
sc.nextLine(); // Consume the leftover '\n'

String s = sc.nextLine(); // Hello World
s = s.substring(0, N);
System.out.println(s); // Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check the input string using an `if` and return the user to input again if it doesn't match the length that you are looking for.

Example:

```
if(s.length() != n) {
    //Take another input
}
```

You can do the above in a loop until this condition is satisfied (maybe a `while` loop).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    String s="";
    do{
       s = sc.nextLine();
    }while(s.length() != n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, all you are doing is reading in `n` strings, and setting `s` to the last one (there will also be an exception thrown if there aren't `n` strings in the input stream). What you need to do is read in a string and compensate for any length errors.

```
if(in.hasNextLine()) {
    s = in.nextLine();
    if(s.length() > n) s = s.substring(0, n); // Cut the string so it is of the desired length
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < n - s.length(); i++) s += " "; // Add spaces until the string is of the desired length
    }
}
```